# Xcode 8 and 9: how to disable code completion when clicking "Tab"

Tags: xcode, xcode8, xcode9

I often use Xcode snippets which contain fields to fill (like <#time_interval#>), I jump between those fields with tabulator. Sometimes, when I fill a field with a `word` and click tab to jump to next field, Xcode automatically changes `word` to first suggestion from autocompletion dropdown, e.g. `HelloWorld`. I don't want to disable suggestions, I just want to disable completing my code on clicking tab. Is there a way to do so? I feel extremely dumb because I make iOS apps for over 7 years already and this setting drives me crazy. It should be something simple somewhere and I must have missed it over and over.

UPDATE for clarification (images):

Click tab and enter one field to fill it:

[image: Click tab and enter one field to fill it]

Type what you want to have there e.g. "literal" word:
[image]

Click tab again to pass onto next `fillMe` field. Expected result:

[image]

Actual result (instead of word "literal" you get Color Literal there which is the first position in autocompletion list):

[image]

Comment: Is it the same with [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/273832#273832)?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not. Check my update for clarification:)

Answer (score 1):

You may use CMD+Z as a workaround - it will revert Xcode autocompletion and leave everything else as is.

Comment: +1, but the point here is to keep productivity high, not keystroke-through your way when using snippets.